# In l293d driver ic ,Can i give a pwm signal to the inputs pin instead of enable pins?

Tags: esp8266, pwm

I have been given a board for programming that uses esp8266 and l293d driver to control 4 motors. But the enable pins of l293d are connected directly to 3.3v.

I wanted to know if it is possible to use the input pins od l293d (pins 2,7,10 and 15)to control the speed of the motor?
L293d pins: In1,2,3,4 are connected directly to esp8266 and output pins are connected to motors.

Comment: Using PWM on the input pins is a perfectly normal way of using this chip.  With the enable pins tied high, the only capability you lose is allowing the motor to coast to a stop.